# Running Hashicorp Vault server on AWS EC2 instance on "provisioner" block

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, hashicorp-vault

I'm creating an AWS instance and I'm trying to run a Vault server when created. My problem is that creation process doesn't ever finish, because the server is not running on background. This is my configuration:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-466768ac"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "my_key"

  tags {
    Name = "Vault"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      agent       = false
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = "${file("/path/to/my_key")}"
    }

    inline = [
      "curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.10.4/vault_0.10.4_linux_amd64.zip",
      "unzip vault_0.10.4_linux_amd64.zip",
      "./vault server -dev -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8200"
    ]
  }

}
```

Basically, I'm downloading Vault via `curl` and running a dev server. Server is actually run (I see it in the terminal logs), but instance creation (by Terraform) never finishes:

```
aws_instance.web: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
aws_instance.web: Still creating... (50s elapsed)
aws_instance.web: Still creating... (1m0s elapsed)
aws_instance.web: Still creating... (1m10s elapsed)
aws_instance.web: Still creating... (1m20s elapsed)
aws_instance.web: Still creating... (1m30s elapsed)
...
```

I have tried to add `&` at the end of the starting Vault server command, in order to not to block the shell but, when I do that, the instance is created but Vault server is not actually started.

How can I start the server in background mode on instance creation?

**EDIT**

I have also tried with `nohup`:

```
nohup ./vault server -dev -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8200
```

But server is not started when terraform finishes...

Comment: Not sure if you want to keep this server with vault, but setting it up as a service and starting it would be maybe a valid choice ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, as @StephenKing told me in a comment, I have created a systemd service instead. This is my configuration:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-466768ac"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "my_key"

  tags {
    Name = "Vault"
  }

  //upload vault.service file (systemd unit)
  provisioner "file" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      agent       = false
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = "${file("/path/to/my/key")}"
    }
    source = "./vault.service"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/vault.service"
  }

  //download vault and start service
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      agent       = false
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = "${file("/path/to/my/key")}"
    }
    inline = [
      "curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.10.4/vault_0.10.4_linux_amd64.zip",
      "unzip vault_0.10.4_linux_amd64.zip",
      "sudo mv /home/ec2-user/vault.service /etc/systemd/system/",
      "sudo systemctl start vault.service"
    ]
  }

}
```

**vault.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Vault dev server

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/vault server -dev -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8200
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Terraform specific thing really, if you were to SSH into an instance and run your command you'd see it block while the process is in the foreground and if you backgrounded it by adding `&` to the end of the command you'd see it quit as soon as you exited your SSH session.

The solution here is to use [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) so that the Vault server process will ignore your `HUP` (or hangup) signal that is triggered when your session exist.

So you should change your command to be:

```
...
    inline = [
      "curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/0.10.4/vault_0.10.4_linux_amd64.zip",
      "unzip vault_0.10.4_linux_amd64.zip",
      "nohup ./vault server -dev -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8200 &"
    ]
...
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. But it's still not working... When I do it via ssh "manually", it works. But it doesn't when I do it using terraform. Process is being killed.

Comment: First part of answer makes sense, but creating a systemd service is better option.  Installing Vault from the HashiCorp apt repo will provide a suitable unit file so you can just enable and start the systemd service with couple of commands.

Comment: @RichVel yep, definitely. This answer was a much more minimal option which solves the immediate issue (they're trying to run a remote command and not wanting it to exit when the provisioner completes). I didn't think to add anything around a systemd service because it was specifically running Vault in dev move but yeah a fully featured answer here would specify a better way to install and run Vault. I apparently also upvoted the comment suggesting to use a service that seems to have prompted the OP to post their more complete answer for running Vault.

Comment: Apparently I had an answer suggesting that approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388157/2291321 as well. We should probably look to pick one of these as a canonical question and show both the `nohup` quick option and a longer, more stable option of creating services instead.