# Terraform local-exec can't run commands in background

Tags: terraform

This post has a solution for remote-exec : [How can I start a remote service using Terraform provisioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207752/how-can-i-start-a-remote-service-using-terraform-provisioning)

I am trying to do the same with local-exec provisioner.

I need to open ssh tunnel on remote node:

```
  #create remote SSH reverse tunnel
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "${self.ip}";
      nohup ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -N -R ${var.chef_zero_port}:localhost:${var.chef_zero_port} ${var.ssh_username}@${self.ip} -M -S /tmp/.ssh_to_${self.ip} &
      sleep 2
    EOT
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash","-c"]
  }
```

tunnel is created but Terraform does not move on to next step.

same if I replace ssh command with:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -fN -R ${var.chef_zero_port}:localhost:${var.chef_zero_port} ${var.ssh_username}@${self.ip} -M -S /tmp/.ssh_to_${self.ip};
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is waiting for all child processes to exit. nohup is detaching from the terminal, but it's still a child process.  Try using `disown` to move the child to init (process 1).

Comment: unfortunately, even disown prevents the resource from coming back