# How can a process started using terraform user_data on an aws_instance continue to run beyond terraform apply finishing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a terraform file which creates an aws_instance and calls a process foo on that instance which should run for 10 mins. This process simulates some traffic which I can monitor elsewhere. I can manually ssh to the instance and run the process and it behaves as expected.

The problem is it seems the process stops running once terraform apply has completed setting everything up (this is my assumption judging by when I stop seeing traffic and see terraform apply finish).

If my assumption is correct is there a way to start the process in such a way that it will outlive terraform finishing?

My terraform file creates the aws_instance like so, where foo has been previously uploaded to another bucket:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
                aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/foo ./
                chmod +x foo
                sudo ./foo
              EOF
  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
                aws s3 cp s3://foobar-bucket/foo ./
                chmod +x foo
                sudo nohup ./foo & disown
              EOF
  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}
```

You can find the difference between `&`, `nohup` and `disown`  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) or maybe use other combination depending on your need.

[How can I start a remote service using Terraform provisioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207752/how-can-i-start-a-remote-service-using-terraform-provisioning)